# How to add partition in hive managed table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveddl

I am creating a partition through the spark in hdfs path not directly in hive. And then I am copying it to the **user/hive/warehouse/test.db/testtbl** through **CP** command. But after **show partitions** command in hive-shell it will not be showing the partition. I also ran the **repair table** command to repair the table and add the partition. But it will not work. How can i add that partitions in hive? Is there another way to add it?

Comment: Partitions in Hive are sub-folders inside table location. And  user/hive/warehouse/test.db/testtbl looks like just table location. You have no partitions, nothing to repair. Is table defined with any partition columns?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone of the below command should work for you.

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>

ALTER TABLE <table_name> ADD PARTITION (<col_name>='<value>')
```